# echo php tags in php

Tags: php, echo

I want to print php tags in php file so I am using

```
$variable="<?php   
include("./$folder/$folder.php"); 
?>";
echo "$variable";
```

but its giving me error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: Most IDEs provide syntax highlighting which help to indicate concatenation errors like this. Check out NetBeans or Eclipse (they're both free to download and use), or even Dreamweaver (which is available for a license fee).

Comment: echo "$variable; is a syntax error. echo $variable

Comment: @karthikr I fixed it but this is not the actual problem but I am trying to echo php tags <?php ?> in php file so its giving me error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes using the backslash character (`\`):

```
$variable="<?php   
include(\"./$folder/$folder.php\"); 
?>";
```

You can also clean up your `echo` expression by dropping the unnecessary quotes:

```
echo $variable;
```

Comment: This will also interpolate the variable `$folder` - It is unclear whether or not this is desired behavior.

Comment: its not about double quotes (this is also a problem) but I am trying to echo php tags <?php ?> in php file so its giving me error

Comment: @user1613566:  You'll need to pass the variable through the [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) function for the tags to be displayed properly.

Comment: @TimCooper Make that `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Alternatively, for the quick and dirty, you can represent your open and close angle brackets as `&lt;` and `&gt;` ie: `echo "&lt;php ...";`